# Улучшение обработчика.

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
$twitch_login = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['twitch_login'] );
$url = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['url'] );
$name = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['name'] );
$query = "INSERT INTO `streams` (twitch_login, url, name) VALUES ('".$twitch_login."','".$url."','".$name."');";
mysql_query ( $query );
header( 'Location: edit?res=2' );
die();
```

По умолчанию он добавляет запись в таблицу streams и перенаправляет пользователя на страницу /edit.php?res=2.

Помогите дописать код, который при добавлении записи будет перенаправлять пользователей на страницу edit?res=3, если найдёт уже созданную запись с одинаковым полем url, при этом запись создавать не будет.

Полагаю, для начала нужно проверить, а существуют ли эти переменные в $_POST вообще.. Но что-то не знаю как это написать.. :(

Comment: if (isset($_POST['url'])) { 
      echo "url was set";
    } else {
      echo "no url param";
    }

Дальше управитесь?

Comment: Уже пробовал дописывать эту строку. Но чему бы $_POST['url'] не был равен — всегда пишет url was set.
Это не то, что нужно. :(

Comment: Смотрите в сторону **INSERT IGNORE**

Comment: ну, я не знаю что там передается, а если так:

    if (isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] != '') {
       echo "url was set <".$_POST['url'].">";
    } else {
       echo "no url param"; 
    }

Угловые скобки специально добавлены, что бы увидеть что там.

Comment: @KoVadim, да ТС не то хотел узнать )) Как я понял, то надо перенаправлять на страницу **А**, если запись была создана и перенаправлять на страницу **В**, если запись не добавлена в следствии того, что значение поля *url* совпадает с добавляемым значением. Поэтому я и написал: **INSERT IGNORE**

Comment: а я прочитал последний абзац вопроса...

Comment: @KoVadim а как проверить наличие в таблице записи с одинаковыми параметрами?

Comment: записей-дубликатов или что текущая добавляемая запись уже есть в базе?
Думаю второе. Это можно решить дубовым методом - вначале делается select и проверяется, есть ли такая запись. А можно сделать поля уникальными, тогда при попытке добавить дубликат, база ругнется.

Comment: Интересно, а если я третий раз повторю, то это возымеет какое-то действие? Или нет смысла тратить силы?

Comment: @KoVadim А можно на примере? :3

После шаманства получил следующее:
<code>
if (isset($_POST['twitch_login']) && $_POST['url'] && $_POST['name'] != '') {
$query = "INSERT INTO `streams` (twitch_login, url, name) VALUES ('".$twitch_login."','".$url."','".$name."');";
mysql_query ( $query );
header( 'Location: edit?r=4' );
}
else {
header( 'Location: edit?r=5' );
}
</code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примитивный пример

```
function post($data)
{
    if(isset($_POST[$data]) && !empty($_POST[$data]))
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = strip_tags($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

        return $_POST[$data];
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function check_url($url)
{
    //Делаем запрос к БД SELECT * FROM...
}

if(post('name') && post('url'))
{
    if(check_url(post('url')))
    {
        //перенаправляем куда то если есть url в базе
    }
    else
    {
        //или создаем новую запись INSERT INTO...
    }
}
```

И не забываем про `SQL Injection`

Comment: Как правильно построить запрос к БД, если:
таблица называется — streams, а название поля — url? :D

Comment: SELECT * FROM streams WHERE url='".$url."'
Экранировать не забудьте